# MySQL - Table is indexed but EXPLAIN says index isn't being used

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, sql-execution-plan, explain

I have a really complex query that is incredibly slow (takes over an hour), so I'm working to improve its performance. Using explain, I can see that one of the tables isn't using the index, which is odd because it does have proper indexing.

```
id  select_type  table     partitions   type    possible_keys    key     key_len  ref    rows   filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE       table_2   (null)       ALL     field_1,field2   (null)  (null)   (null) 8250   0.01        Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

If I look at `table_2`, it is indexed with the same "possbile_keys" suggested by EXPLAIN:

```
UNIQUE KEY `field1` (`field1`,`field2`),
```

In the actual query, the join looks like:

```
JOIN  table_2
      ON  table_2.field1 = table_1.field1
      AND table_2.field2 = table_1.field2
```

Taking a look at the indexes on `table_1`:

```
 KEY `field1` (`field1`,`field2`),
```

Can someone please help me understand what exactly is happening, and why the query isn't using the matching index on my two tables?

Comment: if other  fields in the table are needed (besides field1 and field2) the index may not be used - you might need what is called a "covering index" - that's one idea (without seeing your query or the query plan it is hard to say a lot)

Comment: There are several possible explanations, and I can't tell which one is likely. I'd guess that the columns in the respective tables have incompatible data types or incompatible collations. You should post the full `SHOW CREATE TABLE` report for each table, to clearly show the columnd, data types, indexes, constraints, and table options. Best of all if you use db-fiddle.com so it is reproducible.

Comment: from the "id 1" it looks like it decided to first read table_2 and then join from that (reversing the direction of the join).   it's kind of a heavy hammer to use that limits the optimizer from making sometimes sensible decisions, but you can do `select straight_join ...` to tell it to always do joins in the order specified.

Comment: @ysth, The `id` field of the EXPLAIN report does not enumerate tables, it enumerates queries. Any tables joined within the top-level SELECT statement will report "id 1". Further values of id 2 and so on are used for subqueries, derived tables, or unioned SELECT statements.

Comment: @BillKarwin ah, you are correct, sorry

Answer (score 0):

> Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)

That means that the Optimizer used an even better way.  It read the table2 into memory and built a hash.  This *usually* leads to the query running very fast.

Show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` if you wish to discuss this further.

Note:  Things like `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, and especially `LIMIT` *may* mean that BNL was the 'wrong' way to go.

The setting of `join_buffer_size` partially controls the use of BNL.  If it is set too low, BNL cannot be used.  (If it is set too high, you could run out of RAM -- a worse problem.)